# setting variable as a found value produces "compile error" in vba

Tags: excel, compilation, vba

I'm trying to set a variable based on the value I find, however VB produces "Compile error: invalid identifier", and highlights my variables. I will post code below and identify the line where the error is being produced.

What the code does: 
a) Asks user to input start & end dates in the format week/year
b) If the user does that the code will find the specified value in the range and take the value which is 4 rows below that value. 
That's it - pretty simple & straightforward...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ans As Variant, stDt As Variant, endDt As Variant, endCl As Variant, stCl    As Variant, wsheet As Worksheet, wbook As Workbook, _
fn_stDt As Variant, wk As Integer, rl_st_Dt As String, rl_end_Dt As String,       fn_endDt As Variant

Set wbook = Workbooks("wbook1.xlsm")
Set wsheet = wbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

ans = MsgBox("Would you like to specify the range of dates now?", vbYesNo,    "Select answer")

If ans = vbYes Then
 stDt = Application.InputBox("Please input the starting date", "Start week  for forecast / sales", "ww/yyyy", vbOKCancel, vbQuestion)
    If stCl = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

endDt = Application.InputBox("Please input the end date", "End week for forecast / sales", "ww/yyyy", vbOKCancel, vbQuestion)
    If endCl = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

With wsheet.Range("S5", Range("S5").End(xlToRight))

 Set fn_stDt = .Find(what:=stDt, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
 searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
 If Not fn_stDt Is Nothing Then
    wk = fn_stDt.Offset(-2, 0).Value
    If wk.Value <> wk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then 'Compile Error: Invalid qualifier error appears first here and highlights "wk"
        rl_st_Dt.Value = wk.Offset(-4, 0).Value
    ElseIf wk.Value = wk.Offset(0, 1) Then
        rl_st_Dt.Value = wk.Offset(-4, 1).Value
    End If
End If

End With

With wsheet.Range("S5", Range("S5").End(xlToRight))

 Set fn_endDt = .Find(what:=endDt, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows,  _
 searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
 If Not fn_endDt Is Nothing Then
    wk.Value = fn_endDt.Offset(-2, 0).Value
    If wk.Value <> wk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        rl_end_Dt.Value = wk.Offset(-4, 0).Value
    ElseIf wk.Value = wk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        rl_end_Dt.Value = wk.Offset(-4, 1).Value
    End If
 End If

 End With
 End Sub
```

Could anyone please propose a resolution to the above?

Thanks

Comment: `.value` is not part of integer types.  Remove the `.value`.  Edit: same thing with `rl_st_Dt.Value`.  It is a string and does not have `.value`.

Comment: Done & helped! But now another problem: error 1004: object required. Appears on this line:  Set fn_stDt = .Find(what:=stDt, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False). Most probably due to the fact that it cannot fine the required item?

Comment: This is different question, but try delaring `fn_stDt` as a range instead of a variant.  if that does not work pose a new question.

Comment: alright, will do so. anyways, much thanks for the help!